# Determine the Linear Transformation on the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have these vectors below:

[image]

I have this question below:

Is there any linear transformation L such that L(u1) = u2 and L(u3) = u4, and
that L depicts the plane −x −y + z = 0 on the plane x + z = 0? Explain

I know that i can form a base of the span{u1,u3} and i can have some other vector that is independent of these 2 for example (1,1,0)??

But how can i decide if there exists some Linear Transformations of the two planes?

Comment: $u_2$ is not on the plane $x+z=0$ right?

Comment: @Shagchi How can you see that?

Comment: Plug its coordinates into the equation for the plane and see if it's true.

Comment: @prets Do you mean plug in u2 in -x-y+z = 0 and x + z = 0?

Comment: @JonteYH Yes. I'm assuming that the vectors $u_i$ correspond to the standard basis on say $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. If not, please be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are searching a linear transformation definded as follows:
$$\mathcal{L}([1,0,1]^T)=[1,1,1]^T$$
And:
$$\mathcal{L}([-1,1,0]^T)=[2,1,3]^T$$
Aa you stated, $\mathcal{L}(u_1)$ and $\mathcal{L}(u_2)$ must be in the plane: $x+z=0$ if that linear transformation exist. Consider the first image, in other words the vector $u_2=[1,1,1]^T$. $u_2$. In order to be on the plane has to have coordinates such that $x+z=0$. But, in this case $x=z=1$, so $1+1\neq 0$. Thus, the lonear transformation doesn' exist.

Comment: @Jonte Y: I've edited my post. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thanks now i think i understand you took (1,1,1) from the Linear Transformation and inserted it in the plane-equation :)

Comment: Yes; the plane $x + z = 0$ *means* all points $(x, y, z)$ such that the equation is satisfied.